# Calling node-mongodb-native inside node-csv-parser: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm using [node-csv-parser](http://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parser) to read in csv data and store it in mongodb using mongoose. However I'm trying to speed up the import, and I want to evaluate using the native save method exposed by `node-mongodb-native`, accessed in mongoose using `Model.collection`. (This at the advice of a mongo engineer I spoke to at office hours at Mongo HQ).

`node-csv-parser` fires a `data` event every time it reads in a new line of the csv. Inside this event I read in the line of data, create a new data point from it, and save it in mongo. I can save the data point just fine inside the `data` event using my mongoose model `TestDataPoint`. However if I try to instead create a javascript object for the data point and save it using `TestDataPoint.collection.save`, I get the error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I've tried calling this native save in all sorts of different ways, including getting the collection directly through `mongoose.connection.db.collection("testdatapoints")` and by sending it out to a queue provided by the [async](http://github.com/caolan/async/#queue) module, but always with more or less the same result. I can successfully save a data point using the native driver elsewhere in my code, and even inside the `end` event of the csv import, just not inside the `data` event.

I have also determined through logging that on my current setup (Ubuntu 12.04 on a 64-bit AMD processor, 8 gb RAM), the code iterates through 154 lines of the csv before throwing the stack error, however no data is written to the db from inside this `data` event. It seems there is some kind of recursion happening(?) unintentionally, or perhaps it is some kind of bug between node-csv-parser and node-mongodb-native.

To clarify, with my (edited/updated) sample code below, the log repeats 154 times:

```
about to call native save
just called native save
```

and then says:

```
in native save callback for dataPoint: 1
Native save failed, error:RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
in native save callback for dataPoint: 2
Native save failed, error:RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

up to dataPoint 154, then it repeats the "about to call/just called" another 154 times, then logs the errors for dataPoints 155-308 and so on (I have a lot of data points to import). This 154 number is pretty repeatable, thought I've observed it going through 155 lines at a time once or twice.

It was suggested that I wrap the save call in a `process.nextTick()` to clear the stack. When I try that, in my log I can see that the save is called 154 times, then `process.nextTick()` is called 154 times, then the RangeError is logged 154 times, and the sequence repeats.

I'm running node 0.8.2, mongoose 2.7.2, and mongodb 2.0.4.

```
csv()
    .fromPath(path)
    .on("data", (data, index) ->

        # cellTest is an instance of a Mongoose model object
        newDataPoint = 
            testId: cellTest.testId    # this assignment was causing recursion in the native save
            dataPoint: data[1]
            testTime: data[2]/3600
            cycleIndex: data[3]

        console.log "about to call native save"

        # TestDataPoint is my my mongoose model, which saves fine, but
        # this call throws the RangeError: Maximum stack size exceeded
        TestDataPoint.collection.save newDataPoint, safe:true, (err, dataPoint) ->
            console.log "in native save callback for dataPoint: " + data[1]
            if err
                console.log "Native save failed, error:" + err

        console.log "just called native save"

    .on("end", (count) ->
        newDataPoint = 
            dataPoint: 100            # dummy values
            testTime: 200
            cycleIndex: 300

        # This call works, saves the data point
        TestDataPoint.collection.save newDataPoint, safe:false, null
    )
    .on("error", (err) ->
       console.log err
    )
```

EDIT: SOLVED!

The assignment:

```
testId: cellTest.testId
```

was causing recursion on the save. Something to do with cellTest being an instance of another Mongoose model. Changing the assignment to:

```
testId: parseInt(cellTest.testId)
```

eliminated the recursion and allowed the saves to execute.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `TestDataPoint.collection.save newDataPoint, safe:false, null` is returning any errors in the callback prior to the `RangeError`?

Comment: Yes I have checked. NO other errors but the RangeError

Comment: What is `newDataPoint` right before you get the RangeError?

Comment: Good question. It throws the RangeError for the very first data point (first data line of the csv -- not counting headers), after iterating through 154 lines of the csv file. In fact, If I handle the error and log it I can see in the log 154 save calls, followed by 154 errors (data points 1-154), followed by another 154 save calls, then 154 errors, etc. Perhaps I'll edit my post to reflect this additional detail.

Comment: Does `TestDataPoint` have any embedded documents in it? The `.save` call must be calling itself recursively for some reason. I assume if you remove the `.save` acll and just log your data points everything works fine.

Comment: Bill I think you were on the right track. I figured out the problem and did an edit/answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. In my actual code I set one of the properties of `newDataPoint` equal to an integer property of another Mongoose model object. (Next time I'll know not to "simplify" that detail out of my sample!) This was somehow causing recursion on save.

I fixed it by wrapping a `parseInt()` around the assignment of that value. The save works fine, and about 3x faster than using Mongoose (I know I'm giving up some things in not using Mongoose, but it's fine for my application in which I'm logging a lot of data points where no single point is all that important).